# Video downloaders need

Tags: 13.04, video, youtube, download-manager

I am using Ubuntu 13.04. The browsers I am using are Firefox and Google Chrome.

Now I want to download videos from [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com). Accordingly I've tried some extensions in Firefox and Chrome. But no luck, the connection is being disrupted before the completion of the downloads.

Any suggestions of best downloader of videos from various sites including Youtube?

Thanks

Comment: If the connection has problems, then this is not about the download manager. Unless you don't mean what I think you meant by *disconnecting before the download completed*.

Comment: Voted to close because of "Any suggestions of **best** downloader of videos from various sites". This can elicit opinion-based answers. It would be better if OP asked separate, specific questions about difficulties encountered using specific downloaders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlashGot is an awesome extension for Firefox that does that and much more. You can even send the download URL to an external manager like uGet to ensure that the download connection doesn't drop.

http://flashgot.net/
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/flashgot/

http://uGetdm.com

Chrome has YouTube downloader extensions but none as powerful as Flashgot which is Firefox only.

Comment: *+1* first for your help.how to use *flashgot* and *uGet* to download the videos,whenever I will play videos on youtube? Both I have installed in my laptop.

Comment: if you are requesting for some further help please go to the official uGet Forum at http://ugetdm.com/forum so we can narrow down what you need.